# SQL select and join table result missing 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

My query as below, and I would like to perform join table.

```
SELECT ce.EmployeeName, ce.EmpNo, cd.DepartmentName, cd.DepartmentCode
 FROM CurrentEmployee ce
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyDepartment cd ON ce.EmpNo = cd.EmpNo 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EmpNo , MIN(ClockIn) AS ClockIn, MAX(ClockOut) AS ClockOut FROM RecordHistory GROUP BY EmpNo ) rh
 ON ce.EmpNo = rh.EmpNo
```

After I execute the above query, the result are missing out two columns which are `ClockIn` and `ClockOut`

Is there any syntax error?

Comment: Why don't you select them?

Comment: You are only selecting them in the subquery / derived table, but you're not in the main select...

Comment: Hi @forpas I select `SELECT EmpNo , MIN(ClockIn) AS ClockIn, MAX(ClockOut) AS ClockOut FROM RecordHistory GROUP BY EmpNo` it had result

Comment: This is the query that you join. The returned columns are included in the select statement of your query: `SELECT ce.EmployeeName, ce.EmpNo, cd.DepartmentName, cd.DepartmentCode`

Comment: why am I getting a vote down?

Comment: You don't get things you don't include in the main `select`. This applies to your subquery just as much as it applies to the other, entire tables you `join`. This is a basic fact of SQL.

Comment: So it is because  I didn't `select` for `clockIn` and `clockOut`, even I perform `LEFT JOIN`, thus it didn't appear at my result?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Isolate the first subexpression that doesn't output what you expect & say what you expected & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform:

```
SELECT ce.EmployeeName, ce.EmpNo, cd.DepartmentName, cd.DepartmentCode, rh.ClockIn, rh.ClockOut
 FROM CurrentEmployee ce
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyDepartment cd ON ce.EmpNo = cd.EmpNo 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EmpNo , MIN(ClockIn) AS ClockIn, MAX(ClockOut) AS ClockOut FROM RecordHistory GROUP BY EmpNo ) rh
 ON ce.EmpNo = rh.EmpNo
```

`ClockIn` and `ClockOut` didn't appear in your selection, that's why you are missing those 2 column

Answer (score 1):

You need to include ClockIn and ClockOut in the top level SELECT clause as well as the subquery.

```
SELECT ce.EmployeeName, ce.EmpNo, cd.DepartmentName, cd.DepartmentCode, rh.ClockIn, rh.ClockOut
```